# How to identify errors in android data binding? [AGP 4.0 +]

Tags: android, android-databinding

Recently I noticed that errors from data binding are not descriptive at all. Does anybody know how to find real error message instead of "follow-up" error message?

For example I'm getting errors like this:

```
...\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\company\example\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import com.company.example.databinding.FragmentApplicationDetailsBindingImpl;
                                      ^
  symbol:   class FragmentApplicationDetailsBindingImpl


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Only information I got from this is that error is in `FragmentApplicationDetailsBinding` or in `fragment_application_details.xml` layout file respectively.

Error caused the binding file to fail to generate so it's missing obviously. But no information what exactly went wrong during generation of `FragmentApplicationDetailsBinding`. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild the project if its not work go to File->Invalidate caches / restart.

Comment: Thanks but it's not like a fake error. The error is real and it's not going to disappear by clearing anything. I'm not asking how to fix it, I'm asking why the error message is so useless...

Comment: may be you need to update all your Gradle dependencies and android studio to latest, on the latest version seem provide more clear clarifications on errors